# How to link Database to Web API Project so users in the database can be used for Basic Authentication and Token granting

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have followed the example for using basic authentication and got it working neatly.

You POST to /api/account/register with Username, Password, ConfirmPassword. Visual Studio, during debugging, creates a test database where it stores this credentials.

Then, you POST to /api/token with username, password and grant_type to "login" and get a bearer token to access functions marked with the [Authorize] attribute.

Everything is fine and working. Now, we have a database with plenty of tables, one of these tables holds many accounts with username and password.

How can I make it so the database is linked to the Web API Project so when "logging in" and asking for a token the system compares the username and password to those in the table in our database?

I'm using IIS 10 so I would really appreciate if the answer was also focused towards solving my question with IIS 10 in mind.